# MVC specific files can not download from ftp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC project I have a file library. There are some files in it which comes from specific folder. When I click link to download it, some files couldn't be found, but files are there.

For ex: I have two files at **content/test.jpg** and **content/test2.zxd**

When I click mywebsite.com/content/test.jpg I can download it, but when I click mywebsite.com/content/test2.zxd I can't download it.

Images, videos, sound files, office files, etc. very known extensions works perfectly, but other file extensions causing problem. How can I solve this? Should I have to zip them before upload them?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using ASP.NET on IIS:
Maybe you have to [register unknown static content files for IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap) in your `web.config` with the specific mime type, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
      <remove fileExtension=".zxd" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".zxd" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```